# Why the soft keyboard shows or not when an activity starts?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

When comparing our design between developers, we found a strange behavior. After some analysis we went to this observation.

When the activity starts, on some cases the keyboard appears but sometimes not.

In fact, without a `ScrollView`, the soft keyboard does not appear by default on an `EditText`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TestActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

But when we add a `ScrollView`, the soft keyboard shows up by default.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TestActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" >
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

It only depends on the presence of the `ScrollView`. We can fix that with a specific declaration in the `AndroidManifest`, but this is the default behavior.

I and my fellow developer wonder why is this occurring ?

Comment: I noticed this too and could not find an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I understand of this problem after digging in the code of Android and building some test layouts with an `EditText`.

As `ScrollView` is defined as

```
 public class More ...ScrollView extends FrameLayout { ... }
```

I tried using a `FrameLayout` as a container for an `EditText` item. As a result the software keyboard is not triggered.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="text" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</FrameLayout>
```

But as written in the question, using a ScrollView triggers the software keyboard (I simplified the xml source).

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="text" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</ScrollView>
```

So the element that allows the software keyboard to be triggered is in the `ScrollView` source file.

Edit: after having created my own class `MyFrameLayout` extending FrameLayout and playing with the code, I found that it is something in default scrollview style (`R.attr.scrollViewStyle`) that is responsible for the keyboard to be shown or not...

Edit2: finally the attribute `android:scrollbars` allows the keyboard to be automatically triggered at startup if present...

Comment: Seems like an issue or a strange side effect.

Comment: Wasn't it possible with setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"` ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case android:scrollbars fixed this until I had to add:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

To be able to scroll when keyboard shows.

To be able to use both properties I had to add:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

In the child of the Scrollview

I found focusableInTouchMode answer here: 
[Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Answer (score -1):

This is because when and app is launched, android focuses on the first available view. In the first case it is the EditText, thats why the keyboard pops up. In the second case, the first view is the ScrollView is the first view, which doesn't require keyboard, so it is not shown.
Also, in the first case, you can remove `<requestFocus />`, and on some devices, the keyboard, will not pop up. Hope this helps.

Comment: no you have it switch around, the keyboard shows when its in a scrollview but does not show when its not in one

Comment: hmm. Well, this is weird. I have to look it up.

Comment: true that the requestFocus is not needed. But the problem is elsewhere.